# Ant: How to create an immutable Fileset?

Tags: java, ant

How can I create a dynamic list of files in Ant, then save this list for later use in the build process?  What I am thinking of is something like an immutable `Fileset`.  `Filelist` won't work since it doesn't accept wildcards.

In other words, I want to create a list of files based on include/excludes wildcards that does not change once it's created.  That is, even if more files are added later that pass the inclusion/exclusion rules -- I want to preserve the initial Fileset result (specifically for deletion later in the build process).  Is this possible?

Comment: Seems surprising this isn't easier. Using `<modified/>` which leads to differing results when using the same `refid` is a bit of a gotcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's what I came up with.  Store fileset to property using pathconvert.  Then iterate over files later in the build, doing whatever you need to with them.  In my case, deleting them.

```
<macrodef name="storeBuildState">
    <sequential>
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}" id="current.fileset">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <pathconvert pathsep="," property="current.fileset.prop" refid="current.fileset"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef> 



<macrodef name="deleteStoredBuildState">
    <sequential>
        <for list="${current.fileset.prop}" param="file">
            <sequential>
                <delete file="@{file}" verbose="true" />
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```